# How can I run a powershell script on an entire Azure management group to span multiple subscriptions?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-management-groups

How can I run a powershell script on an entire Azure management group to span multiple subscriptions? I need to export resource inventories from multiple subscriptions with a single run in the same file.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use Azure Resource Graph which supports PowerShell, CLI and Azure SDK for .NET.

```
Search-AzGraph -Query "Resources | summarize count()"
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/resource-graph/first-query-powershell

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/resource-graph/samples/starter?tabs=azure-powershell#count-resources